# Which method should be called when the app goes to the background?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Which method should be called when the app goes to the background?, In xamarin.Android and xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xamarin.Android its [OnPause()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnPause/) and Xamarin.iOS its [DidEnterBackground().](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.DidEnterBackground/)

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms, the [OnSleep()](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/app-lifecycle/#Lifecycle_Methods) method will be called when the app goes into the background on all platforms.